# Am I thinking in the right way about this Negative weights using Dijkstra's Algorithm graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I've been trying to wrap my head around why Dijkstra's algorithm doesn't work on negative weighted graphs and I understand all examples that has a further node pointing back to a node that has been fully explored. But this examples does my head in;

[image]

Would I be correct in thinking that; first `A` is explored. `A->B` will be `1` and `A->C` will be `100`. Then `B` is explored and sets `B->D` to `2`. Then **D** is explored because currently it has the shortest path back to the source (i.e. At the top of the priority queue)?

Would I be correct in saying that if `B->D` was `100`, `C` would've been explored first (since `A->D` is `101`)?

The one thing that people didn't really mention in every explanation was that a node has been explored/visited, it can't be updated anymore because Dijkstra works on a priority queue. I just find it hard to wrap my head around why `D` is visited before `C` in this case.

Comment: You have it right.  The algorithm only works if the shortest path to a node is known when it is removed from the queue, and that just isn't necessarily true if some later node might have a negative-weighted link to it.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Why don't you place that as an answer and I'll tick it. Was I correct in my second statement about changing B->C to 100?

Comment: I don't think my answer adds a lot of value to the site, so I'll leave room in case someone wants to provide a nice explanation.  Yes, your second statement is correct.

Comment: it's going to fail because Djikstra's algorithm is based on the fact that when a node is explored/closed then the shortest path to this path was already found. You can not state that when there might be negative weights in the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straightforward: when a node using Djikstra's algorithm is explored/visited/closed this means that **you have found the shortest path to that node**, therefore this node **does not need to be reexplored or revisited**, you already know the shortest path to the node.

For instance, when you select D to be explored there are two paths in the PQ:

- A-B-D with cost 2
- A-C   with cost 100

and the path with least cost is selected. Then, it's obvious that if arc costs are always positive there's no way that you can find a shortest path to D going through A-C. The shortest path to D has been found and the node is closed.

All this reasoning is however not true when negative arc costs are allowed, so that's why Djikstra's algorithm does not work for them.

Answer (score 0):

I think Dijkstra algorithm that you are describing operates only on positive weight functions. In particular Dijkstra algorithm gives a valid metric space structure on every weighted (positively) graph. On the other hand this seems to be not the case for arbitrary weighted graphs. Take for instance the graph with two nodes A and B and one edge between them with weight -5. In this case this will not give a distance between A and B. So what you describing, I think would fall into some sort of modified Dijkstra model and the interpretation of going from one node to another can no longer be interpreted as distance between the nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The algorithm I am using above is only correct on positive weight functions. The explanation I gave above was what (I think) causes the algorithm to fail to see `A->C->D` being the shortest path.

Comment: What is your definition for "shortest path" in this case? is it the sequence of edges from A to D that gives you the smallest weight sum?

Comment: Yes, shortest path to D.

Comment: Then it is A->C->D.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I'm trying to understand why Dijkstra's Algorithm would fail to see that though (and subsequently mark `A->B->D` as the answer).